# Angular Material Data table filtering for email and phone Number not working

Tags: angular-material

I'm am using angular material table and I can't filter by email and phone number in the table

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
     this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
      }
```

Comment: Your function seems correct. Can't say much without seeing the rest parts of the project. Consider adding a stackblitz.